# How to express the expectation of a vector of Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

I am reading this paper
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07370.pdf

The problem setup is as follows:

[image]

I am trying to express the expectation,

$$\mathbb{E}_{p(b)}[f(b,\theta)]$$

into a summation.

---

For example, suppose that $b$ is a Bernoulli random variable in $\mathbb{R}$, then the expectation can be expressed as

$$\mathbb{E}_{p(b)}[f(b,\theta)] = \theta f(1,\theta) +(1-\theta)f(0,\theta)$$

---

Now suppose that $b$ is a Bernoulli random variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am trying to figure out how write this summation.

Is it something like,...
$$\mathbb{E}_{p(b)}[f(b,\theta)] = \theta_1 f(1,\theta_1) +(1-\theta_1)f(0,\theta_1) + \theta_2 f(1, \theta_2) + (1-\theta_2) f(0,\theta_2) + \ldots + \theta_n f(1,\theta_n) + (1-\theta_n) f(0, \theta_n)$$

where $\theta = (\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case of $b \in \mathbb R^n$ with $n=2$ then

$$\mathbb E[f(b,\theta)] = \sum_{b \in \mathcal B} p(b) f(b,\theta) $$

where $\mathcal B = \{0,1\}^n = \{0,1\}^2 = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$. Inserting these the sum can be explicitly written as

$$p(0,0) f(0,0,\theta) + p(0,1) f(0,1,\theta) + p(1,0) f(1,0,\theta) + p(1,1) f(1,1,\theta).$$

Using the assumption of independence $p(b) = p(b_1,b_2) = p_1(b_1)p_2(b_2)$ the simultaneous probability mass function can be written as product of marginals and applying further that $p_j(b_j)$ is $\theta_j$ when $b_j=1$ and $1-\theta_j$ when $b_j=0$ it follows that

$$(1-\theta_1)(1-\theta_2) f(0,0,\theta) + (1-\theta_1)\theta_2 f(0,1,\theta) + \theta_1(1-\theta_2) f(1,0,\theta) + \theta_1\theta_2 f(1,1,\theta).$$